# Telegraf is collecting metrics from jolokia but not writing metrics to influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I have telegraf configuration set-up in a docker base image and am seeing an issue with one of the services where jolokia metrics are captured but not written to influxDB. Other services using the same base image have no issue writing to InfluxDB.

**telegraf.log file for service with issue:**
    2017/09/25 21:25:00 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    115.245395ms
    2017/09/25 21:25:05 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    83.221324ms
    2017/09/25 21:25:10 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    75.461556ms
    2017/09/25 21:25:15 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    99.841166ms
    2017/09/25 21:25:20 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    62.729338ms

**telegraf.log file for service without issue:**
    2017/09/25 20:45:20 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    480.84182ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:25 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    481.822055ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:30 Wrote 2 metrics to output influxdb in 57.553898ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:30 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    481.855258ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:35 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    481.826305ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:40 Wrote 2 metrics to output influxdb in 62.126203ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:40 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    481.883574ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:45 Gathered metrics, (5s interval), from 1 inputs in 
    481.851454ms
    2017/09/25 20:45:50 Wrote 2 metrics to output influxdb in 70.463902ms
Appreciate any pointers on the root cause for this issue. I can post additional info on telegraf.conf file if needed.

Thanks,
Maddy